# Is there a way to ask a question and get input in the same line on Java?

Tags: java

I am having trouble gathering user input and ask the question on one line.

The current code I am using is:

```
public class ClinicRegistration {

private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String [] args){
    
    String name;
    
    SortedPriorityQueue<Date,String> regularQueue = new SortedPriorityQueue<>();
    SortedPriorityQueue<Integer,String> emergencyQueue = new SortedPriorityQueue<>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();
    }
}

}
```

The current response I get is:

```
hi
my
name
is
banana
Please enter your name: Please enter your name: Please enter your name: Please enter your name:
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions!

EDIT:

Ideally each line should be:

```
Please enter your name: John
Please enter your name: Chris
```

and each name is stored to the name variable

Comment: What is your environment?  Like is this inside an IDE?  It feels like your environment is just broken, it shouldn't work this way.  Try this from a console to double check.

Comment: @markspace I just used an online compiler and it worked as expected. Right now I am using Apache Netbeans as my IDE (as recommended by my instructor). I guess my next question would be how do I fix this?

Comment: I use NetBeans.  It works fine, the output appears on the right line.  Check Help -> About for the version number, I have 11.1

Comment: @markspace I have "Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0" installed

Comment: You might have to contact their support or downgrade your IDE.  I usually stick to odd number versions just for this problem (bugs get fixed in the odd numbered versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a flush call to your code:

```
System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
System.out.flush();
name = sc.nextLine();
```

This should force the prompt to print out before input is accepted.

Comment: I believe `System.out` flushes its output automatically after each call, but this idea is worth trying at least.

Comment: That is often only true of `System.err`.

Comment: I just tried it to no avail, any other recommendations?

Comment: I just looked at `System.out` in a debugger, its internal `autoflush` is set to `true`.  I'm pretty sure this is also documented somewhere, though I can't think now where. @Steve

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: I got the output to print but only after the first input, in addition, I still type on the next line.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add a short explanation to your answer. Why should your code work? What is it doing? Explanation is very helpful to clear any doubt... Thank you